# how to run app with mdf database in another pc

Tags: c#, winforms, mdf

I have a windows form app project with mdf database 
the app work fine in my pc
but when i try it on another pc it dont work and no connection to database
(the database with app in same folder)

This is connection string

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Contact.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

How to use my app with this mdf database in another pc?

It run in my pc when I installed localDB 2016 but I can't install localDB 2016 in second pc because it is 32bit machine.

Comment: with no database engine on the another pc you could not make it. If you stick to SQL Server you should install SQL Express (or a licenced version one) and attach it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute queries against MDF files, you cannot use them directly without attaching them with database service.

Best solution in your case will be to install SQL Express or appropriate database service on the second computer.  Then you can take back up from first machine and restore on second machine.  OR you can also create brand new database on second machine using your database creation scripts and use it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sql express? did u mean sql server ?

Comment: i had installed sql server 2012

Comment: i use 2012 sql managment studio but i dont know how to connect from my app to database in server of sql managment studio

Comment: sql express is the free version of sql server.  if you have sql server 2012 already installed then you can take backup from first machine and then restore it on secondd machine.  Use connection string to connect with sql server 2012 instance and appropriate database name.

Comment: You can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017 for attaching MDF to sql server.  I would suggest to take Backup / restore route instead of MDF attach.